# Museclick and mousemove event in batch

Tags: bash, batch-file, mouseevent

I am wondering how to get the mousemove and mouseclick events in batch. Can anybody help me?
Thx for advice!

...or maybe in bash...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is no, you can't.

To point you in the right direction look at global keyboard and mouse hooks for C/C++/C#.

There are plenty of [discussions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/d3e60bb8-aa67-46b6-a6a6-3f1ad6611f50) on the web about these.